# ¿Cómo funcionan las notificaciones en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, artisan, notification

Estoy intentando crear notificaciones en Laravel 5.8 con los recursos propios de este. Para ello he creado una autenticación, con su migración y modelo de usuarios. Aquí no hay nada especial. Es la autenticación que crea Laravel por defecto. He creado algunos usuarios desde tinker.

Para la tabla de notificaciones he usado `php artisan notifications:table`, y he creado la tabla según la migración que genera artisan. El modelo lo he creado así:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notification extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $table = 'notifications';

    protected $fillable = [
        'type',
        'notifiable_type',
        'notifiable_id',
        'data',
        'read_at',
    ];
}
```

Luego he creado la clase de la notificación, con `php artisan make:notification Messages`. En la clase he usado el método `toArray()`, así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class Messages extends Notification
{
    protected $mensaje;

    use Queueable;

    public function __construct($mensaje)
    {
        $this->mensaje = $mensaje;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'database',
        ];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->mensaje->toArray();
    }
}
```

En el controlador que recibe el mensaje desde un formulario y debe grabar la notificación, tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    $reglas = [
        'mensaje' => 'required',
        'destinatario' => 'required|exists:users,id',
    ];

    $errores = [
        'mensaje.required' => 'Debe incluir el texto del mensaje.',
        'destinatario.required' => 'Debe seleccionar un destinatario.',
        'destinatario.exists' => 'El destinatario elegido no existe.',
    ];

    $request->validate($reglas, $errores);

    $mensaje = Notification::create([
        'remitente_id' => auth()->id(),
        'destinatario_id' => $request->destinatario,
        'mensaje' => $request->mensaje,
    ]);

    $receptor = User::find($request->destinatario);

    $receptor->notify(new Messages($mensaje));

    return back()->with('grabado', 'El mensaje ha sido enviado');
}
```

Por supuesto, me he asegurado de que los nombres de las variables recibidas en la petición son coincidentes con los de los campos del formulario. Ahí no hay error.

El caso es que, al intentar ejecutarlo, me lanza una excepción como la siguiente:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `notifications` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2020-05-10 11:33:25, 2020-05-10 11:33:25))
```

Pensé que, puesto que la tabla de notificaciones ha creado el campo `id` como de tipo `uuid` primario (esto lo hace artisan por defecto) en lugar del típico autoincrementable, debería establecer un valor para este campo, así que modifique el objeto `$mensaje` en el controlador, así:

```
$mensaje = Notification::create([
    'id' => uniqid(),
    'remitente_id' => auth()->id(),
    'destinatario_id' => $request->destinatario,
    'mensaje' => $request->mensaje,
]);
```

Para ello, en el modelo `Notification` añadí el campo `id` a la matriz `$fillable`. La excepción cambia entonces a la siguiente:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `notifications` (`id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (5eb7ed23847b6, 2020-05-10 12:01:39, 2020-05-10 12:01:39))
```

Así, ahora me pide un valor para `type`. Lo añado en el controlador, así:

```
$mensaje = Notification::create([
    'id' => uniqid(),
    'type' => 'Mensaje',
    'remitente_id' => auth()->id(),
    'destinatario_id' => $request->destinatario,
    'mensaje' => $request->mensaje,
]);
```

Y entonces la excepción cambia a:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'notifiable_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `notifications` (`id`, `type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (5eb7edb689245, Mensaje, 2020-05-10 12:04:06, 2020-05-10 12:04:06))
```

Y aquí la cosa ya se pone peor. Se supone que los campos `notifiable_id` y `notifiable_type` debería tomarlos directamente, ¿no? De todos modos, los añadí en el controlador, así:

```
$mensaje = Notification::create([
    'id' => uniqid(),
    'type' => 'Mensaje',
    'notifiable_id' => $request->destinatario,
    'notifiable_type' => User::class,
    'remitente_id' => auth()->id(),
    'destinatario_id' => $request->destinatario,
    'mensaje' => $request->mensaje,
]);
```

Y ahora la excepción es la siguiente:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'data' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `notifications` (`id`, `type`, `notifiable_id`, `notifiable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (5eb7ee751d6a1, Mensaje, 4, App\User, 2020-05-10 12:07:17, 2020-05-10 12:07:17))
```

Todo esto me lleva a dos preguntas básicas: ¿Cómo funcionan las notificaciones? y, la más importante. Si todo debo definirlo manualmente en el controlador ¿Para que sirven las clases de notificación? ¿Cómo es la forma correcta de hacer esto para sacarle partido a estos recursos? He estado mirando la documentación oficial, y un montón de sitios en Internet, pero no encuentro ningún ejemplo operativo que me permita deducir la forma correcta de uso.

Un log de ejemplo:

```
[2020-05-14 15:49:25] local.ERROR: Array to string conversion {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Array to string conversion at C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Str.php:353)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Str.php(353): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Array to string...', 'C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\...', 353, Array)
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException.php(56): Illuminate\\Support\\Str::replaceArray('?', Array, 'insert into `no...')
#2 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException.php(39): Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException->formatMessage('insert into `no...', Array, Object(ErrorException))
#3 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(665): Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException->__construct('insert into `no...', Array, Object(ErrorException))
#4 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `no...', Array, Object(Closure))
#5 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(459): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('insert into `no...', Array, Object(Closure))
#6 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(411): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->statement('insert into `no...', Array)
#7 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php(2646): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->insert('insert into `no...', Array)
#8 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder.php(1353): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->insert(Array)
#9 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php(815): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->__call('insert', Array)
#10 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php(667): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->performInsert(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder))
#11 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOneOrMany.php(281): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->save()
#12 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php(1124): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOneOrMany->Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\{closure}(Object(App\\Notification))
#13 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOneOrMany.php(282): tap(Object(App\\Notification), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\Channels\\DatabaseChannel.php(20): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOneOrMany->create(Array)
#15 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender.php(144): Illuminate\\Notifications\\Channels\\DatabaseChannel->send(Object(App\\User), Object(App\\Notifications\\UsersMessages))
#16 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender.php(103): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->sendToNotifiable(Object(App\\User), '4cf6a610-65b7-4...', Object(App\\Notifications\\UsersMessages), 'database')
#17 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\Localizable.php(19): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->Illuminate\\Notifications\\{closure}()
#18 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender.php(105): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->withLocale(NULL, Object(Closure))
#19 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender.php(77): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->sendNow(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection), Object(App\\Notifications\\UsersMessages))
#20 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\ChannelManager.php(39): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->send(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection), Object(App\\Notifications\\UsersMessages))
#21 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\RoutesNotifications.php(18): Illuminate\\Notifications\\ChannelManager->send(Object(App\\User), Object(App\\Notifications\\UsersMessages))
#22 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\HomeController.php(75): App\\User->notify(Object(App\\Notifications\\UsersMessages))
#23 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\HomeController->sendMessage(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#25 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('sendMessage', Array)
#26 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\HomeController), 'sendMessage')
#27 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#28 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(680): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#29 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#53 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(657): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(623): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#55 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(612): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#56 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#57 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#59 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#60 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#62 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#63 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#64 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#65 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#66 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#67 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#68 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#69 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#70 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#71 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(163): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#72 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#73 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#74 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#75 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#76 C:\\laragon\\www\
otificaciones\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#77 {main}
"}
```

Comment: No creo que tengas que insertar manualmente la notificación en la BD, eso no se menciona en nigún momento en la documentación. Prueba cambiando `$mensaje = Notification::create([
        'remitente_id' => auth()->id(),
        'destinatario_id' => $request->destinatario,
        'mensaje' => $request->mensaje,
    ]);` a `$mensaje = [
        'remitente_id' => auth()->id(),
        'destinatario_id' => $request->destinatario,
        'mensaje' => $request->mensaje,
    ];`

Comment: Y en el método `toArray` de la clase Messages retorna ese mismo array que recibes en el constructor  `return $this->mensaje;`

Comment: Pues no va. Me da una excepción `Array to string conversion`. Podrías especificar más? Tú cómo lo haces funcionar? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene porque, aunque `$mensaje` en el controlador es un objeto de la clase que haya creado (en tu ejemplo, `Notification`), a la clase de la notificación llega como una matriz.

La solución es cambiar el controlador de la clase, así:

```
public function __construct($mensaje)
{
    $this->mensaje = collect($mensaje);
}
```

Con esto, ya estás manejando una colección, que es lo que necesitas en las notificaciones.

Comment: Guau. Funcionó. Tan sencillo, y ni lo encontraba. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Estos serían los pasos básicos para enviar una notificación por email, guardar las notificaciones enviadas en Base de Datos, y pasarle datos desde el controlador a la notificación para guardarlos en la BD y personalizar el mensaje.

---

**Enviar por Email**

Asumiendo que ya tienes configuradas las credenciales para enviar emails y eso está funcionando...

Creas la clase de notificación:

```
php artisan make:notification TestNotification
```

Te aseguras que en tu modelo `User` uses el trait `Notifiable` (ya viene por defecto, pero por si acaso):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable; // <- Esto!!!
}
```

Y en el controlador puedes hacer algo así:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    $receptor = User::find($request->destinatario);

    $receptor->notify(new TestNotification());

    return back()->with('enviado', 'La notificación ha sido enviada.');
}
```

Hasta aquí, con sólo eso, ya se estaría enviando la notificación por email al acceder a ese método del controlador.

---

**Guardar en Base de Datos**

Para guardar las notificaciones en Base de Datos, crea la migración y córrela:

```
php artisan notifications:table

php artisan migrate
```

Agrega el elemento `'database'` al array que retorna el método `via()` de tu clase de notificación:

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'mail', 
        'database', // <- agrega esto!!
    ];
}
```

Y en el método `toArray()`, retorna un array con datos que quieras que se guarden:

```
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'alguna_clave' => 'algun dato',
        'otra_clave' => 'otro dato',
    ];
}
```

Listo, ya se estarán guardando las notificaciones en base de datos.

---

**Personalizar el mensaje y lo que se guarda en la BD**

En el controlador construye un array y pásaselo a tu clase de notificación como argumento:

```
public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
    $receptor = User::find($request->destinatario);

    $mensaje = [
        'remitente_id' => auth()->id(),
        'destinatario_id' => $receptor->id,
        'mensaje' => 'algún mensaje',
    ];

    $receptor->notify(new TestNotification($mensaje));

    return back()->with('grabado', 'La notificación ha sido enviada y guardada.');
}
```

Y en la clase de notificación recibe el argumento en el constructor:

```
class TestNotification extends Notification
{
    protected $message; // declara alguna propiedad para asignarle el valor que recibas en el constructor.

    public function __construct($message) // <- aquí lo recibes.
    {
        $this->message = $message; // <- aquí se lo asignas a la propiedad de la clase para poder usarlo en los otros métodos.
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->message; // <- aquí le indicas que lo quieres guardar en la base de datos
        // puedes construir el array a guardar a tu gusto, para este ejemplo simplemente retorna el mismo array que llegó desde el controlador
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line($this->message['mensaje']) // <- aquí usas los elementos del array para personalizar la notificación
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Eso es todo!');
    }

}
```

---

Así lo hice funcionar.
Lo de crear un modelo e insertar la notificación manualmente como muestras en la pregunta, no va.

Comment: Hola, @porloscerros. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta tan detallada. Sin embargo,no he logrado hacerlo funcionar. Poniéndolo todo exactamente como me indicas, obtengo una excepción Array to String conversion. He estado mirando la documentación, y diferentes videos en youtube, no logro encontrar el origen del problema.

¿Puede ser necesaria alguna configuración específica? En la documentación tampoco he encontrado ninguna referencia a configuración para las notificaciones, pero es lo único que se me ocurre.

Comment: Hola. En alguna parte estás pasando un array donde se espera un string, si pudieses ver en los logs de laravel el trazo de la excepción para ver específicamente dónde se lanza, mejor. De todos modos se me ocurren dos posibilidades. Una que sea una excepción de SQL al guardar en BD, pero es la menos posible, ya que la creación de la tabla y el guardado se hace automáticamente. La otra es que le estés pasando directamente el array a una línea de la notificación, por ej `->line($this->message)` en vez de  `->line($this->message['mensaje'])` o algo parecido.

Comment: Si puedes agregar el trazo de la excepción a la pregunta para ubicar exactamente dónde se lanza, mejor. Los log están en `/tu-proyecto/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: Miré el log, pero no aporta gran cosa, o yo no sé leerlo adecuadamente. Lo he añadido a la pregunta, ya que aquí no me cabe. Como se ve, es bastante confuso.